# How to sort items by a datetime field

Tags: fieldtype

`Article Publish Date` is a field of type `Datetime`

```
List<Item> articles = GetArticles();

articles = articles.OrderByDescending(x => x.Fields[Constants.Templates.Article.Fields.ArticlePublishDate]).ToList();
```

The above line of code throws an error:

> At least one object must implement IComparable.

How can this be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mahendra's answer will work, but it is also possible to cast your field to a `Sitecore.Data.Fields.DateField` and retrieve the `DateTime` property, which will actually properly parse the field value and return a sortable `DateTime` value. I would implement it like this:

```
List<Item> articles = GetArticles();

articles = articles.OrderByDescending(x => ((Sitecore.Data.Fields.DateField)x.Fields[Constants.Templates.Article.Fields.ArticlePublishDate]).DateTime).ToList();
```

Comment: This is the more reliable (albeit likely slower) way to solve the original question.

Comment: @DanSinclair Definitely slower, but not noticeable unless you're running on a very large number of articles. But if you are doing that, your performance problem would come from fetching a large number of articles from the Sitecore database, not from parsing the datetime.

Comment: @MatthewFitzGerald-Chamberlain If the date field is empty. How will it be in the order. Will it throw an error.

Comment: @Qwerty It would be parsed as `DateTime.MinValue` so it would appear last in the list, same as in your's and Mahendra's

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to sort by field not value, try below by removing `Fields`-

```
List<Item> articles = GetArticles();

articles = articles.OrderByDescending(x => x[Constants.Templates.Article.Fields.ArticlePublishDate]).ToList();
```